# PHP form appending to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to send data to SQL database from a PHP form.  Web page doesn't pull any errors when connecting to database, but can't figure out how to pass these variables from an html into mysql.

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
    mysqli_connect_error());

    $sql = "insert into music (song, artist, album, year genre)
            values('$song', '$artist', '$album', '$year', '$genre',)";
    $dbc->query($sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the form method is POST, you would use the `$_POST[]` array. The HTML form element `id` is what you use to access the array element.

For example, if you have `<input type="text" id="name">` you would use `$_POST['name']` to get the name from the form.

Alternatively, you could use `$_REQUEST['']` which contains `$_POST`, `$_GET`, and `$_COOKIE` values.

To prevent SQL injection and other problems dealing with user input, you'll also want to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Something like:

```
$firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['firstName']);
```

Then insert `$firstName` into your query.

Further info for `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:
[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp)

Comment: You should point out about `mysqli_real_escape_string( )` to give OP a layer of protection.

Comment: Very good point, @PhiterFernandes. Feel free to edit my answer to include that :)

Comment: I see you're beginning your journey on Stack Overflow and you'll come across many php questions using `mysql_*` and directly adding `$_POST` and `$_GET` to the queries. You'll have to warn them every time about SQL Injection, this will get you more upvotes.